# Display Preview of All Uploaded Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

Is there any way to show the preview of PDF, Word, Excel and Text files in webform using image tag?? I have uploaded few files and now i want to see the preview of those files. I have searched on internet and came to know that there are few third party tools to show preview of pdf files but they are expensive. So is there any other way to show the preview of those files.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To display a pdf convert it to tiff or jpeg format [see here for an example](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
Displaying office files can be trickier - if your end users are potentially using IE then you will need a 3rd party component - edraw office viewer works well [see here](http://www.edrawsoft.com/products.php) but it does cost